# Generate entropy to create RSA keys

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, openssh, cryptography

I was wondering on how I could make my server as most secure as possible. I use OpenSSH to connect to it, using RSA keys. However, something bothers me about that method: to generate the RSA keys, I generated no "entropy".

Here's an example: on Windows, to encrypt a folder using VeraCrypt, the user is asked to perform interactions (mouse moves) to make the RSA keys more random. Can we reproduce that in openssl or libressl?

Besides, I've read somewhere that you could potentially dramatically reduce the time to brute-force a RSA private keys if you know the design of the CPU (typically the government).

Comment: "I've read somewhere that you could potentially dramatically reduce the time to brute-force a RSA private keys if you know the design of the CPU (typically the government)." No, that just makes it easier to perform *side channel attacks*. It is best to generate those without any additional applications / browsers running. Some people don't trust RDRAND, an instruction that depends on entropy gained from the CPU itself. So Open Source platforms generally just use it as one possible source of entropy for the OS RNG.

Comment: AMD has a dangerous RDRAND bug that makes it generate non-random numbers after suspend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read somewhere that you could potentially dramatically reduce the time to brute-force an RSA private keys if you know the design of the CPU (typically the government).

It's important to understand the reason, the entropy you describe is not applicable to RSA keys.

> In RSA, this asymmetry is based on the practical difficulty of the
>   factorization of the product of two large prime numbers, the
>   "factoring problem".

Source: [RSA (cryptosystem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))

Likewise,

> The whole point of the certificate generation is to create random
>   numbers from either your file, or from a random number generator, as
>   noise input into an algorithm to generate very large primes. The trick
>   is getting to those prime numbers. With an entropy pool of 4096 bits,
>   at full up, all the time, as haveged(8) will be providing, the ability
>   of someone to regenerate the same primes, even if they have full
>   knowledge of your system is highly improbable.

Source: [Good entropy source for generating OpenSSL keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12571/good-entropy-source-for-generating-openssl-keys)

OpenSSL and LibreSSL by default uses the kernel of the operating system as a source of entropy.  **There are no known vulnerabilities, other than a brute force attempt, to break an RSA key of significant and appropriate size.**

OpenSSL and LibreSSL itself do not support want you to want.  However, You can use something like [PuTTY Key Generator](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html), to do what you want. **When using OpenSSL to generate the certificate you would need to use the key(s) that are generated using the appropirate OpenSSL command.**

> Can we reproduce that in openssl or libressl?

OpenSSL and LibreSSL do not support collecting entropy from mouse movements.

Comment: You say `OpenSSL and LibreSSL by default uses the kernel of the operating system as a source of entropy` and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)#Linux_kernel) says `The Linux kernel generates entropy from […], mouse movements, and […]`. If both statements are true then in Linux OpenSSL and LibreSSL do collect entropy from mouse movements; indirectly and not only from mouse movements, but still.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Random mouse movements alone, are not going to increase the security of an RSA key, which is the multiple sources of entropy is required.